# Menu less indicator not working as expected

Tags: css, less

I'm working on an indicator in less for my wordpress menu.

Here is the link to the code on codepen:

```
[https://codepen.io/Ricods/pen/mGzeQN][1]
```

I have some problems with it:

- The first item is broken in two rows. I was thinking about adding a pseudo-class first-child to change the width. But I don't know if it's the right way to handle it?
- How to get rid of the empty spaces after the item names?

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the number of menu items you can set it with self width for each item you have and not with dinamic scss , if you would have more items in menu it still will break the same as you have now. And also the pseudo class will not make any difference !